# How to filter on tree grid?

Tags: angularjs, tree

I was wondering how to filter on an angular tree grid.

[This](https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive) is already implemented in my app but I don't know how to make `filterable:true` actually do something.

Any help much appreciated!